# unix_timestamp of pyspark.sql.functions get null only for the majority of values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, unix-timestamp, apache-spark-sql

I try to convert a columns from string to timestamp with this code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum, avg, count, first, col
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp, col, datediff
import csv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
        .getOrCreate()
    df=spark.read.csv("in\SETP11.csv")
    df = df.selectExpr('_c0 as USER_ID', '_c1 as timestamp', '_c2 as location')
    df.show()
    df = df.withColumn('timestamp', unix_timestamp('timestamp', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'))
    df.show()
```

but i get null (the function return a value only for some)

```
+-------+---------+--------+
|USER_ID|timestamp|location|
+-------+---------+--------+
|      1|     null|     321|
|      1|1359262.2|     386|
|      1|1359271.2|     386|
|      1|1359273.6|     386|
|      1|1359273.6|     386|
|      1|1359274.8|     386|
|      1|1359281.4|     386|
|      1|1359282.0|     386|
|      1|     null|     386|
|      1|     null|     386|
|      1|     null|     386|
|      1|     null|     386|
+-------+---------+--------+
```

how to fix this ?, where is the problem ?

keyword : python apache-spark pyspark unix-timestamp

Comment: Can you show the raw data `in\SETP11.csv`? `null` is when the format does not match.

Comment: I feel you are selecting wrong columns. Try, `df = df.withColumn('timestamp', col('timestamp).cast(DoubleType())`